# Django REST: Unsupported media type 'application/xml' in request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using http://django-rest-framework.org/ Tokens and trying to now get a token. I have followed the guides. However,

When I try to make a post to the URL:

```
Request Url: http://127.0.0.1:8001/api-token-auth/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 415
Params: {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test123"
}
```

I get the following response

```
{
    "detail": "Unsupported media type 'application/xml' in request."
}
```

Why is this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're sending a request using XML content.

As the [docs note](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#tokenauthentication), the obtain_auth_token view expect a JSON request.

Make sure the data is JSON encoded, and that you're correctly setting the 'Content-Type' header to `'application/json`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because django-rest-framework can return data in more than one format. It apparently decides on which format by looking at the "Accept:" HTTP header in the request. Try changing the value of this header to something like "application/json" for example.

Comment: That's similar, but actually incorrect accept headers would return a `406 Not Acceptable` reponse.

Comment: Oh, okay. I did not know about the specifity of obtain_auth_token.